# AWS Glue transform string value from postgres to json array

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I am new to AWS Glue and pyspark. I have a table in RDS which contains a varchar field `id`. 
I want to map `id` to a String field in the output json which is inside a json array field (let's say `newId`):

> {
>  "sources" : [
>   "newId" : "1234asdf"
>  ]
> }

How can I achieve this using the transforms defined in the pyspark script of the AWS Glue job.

Comment: So for each row in the table, you want to create a key value pair "newId":"some_value", with some_value being the value in the "id" column of the row? Do you plan to add more fields to the object you are creating for each row? Any reason not to have the collection be the root, rather than sticking the collection under the "sources" collection object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [AWS Glue Map Transformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map-example) to map the string field into a field inside a JSON array in target.

```
NewFrame= Map.apply(frame=OldFrame, f=map_fields)
```

and define a function `map_fields` like such:

```
def map_fields(rec):
    rec["sources"] = {}
    rec["sources"] = [{"newID": rec["id"]}]
    del rec["id"]
    return rec
```

Make sure to delete the original field as done in `del rec["uid"]` otherwise the logic doesn't work.